# How to calculate the prediction interval for my 24-hour forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, prediction-interval

I'm doing time series analysis and I would like to calculate the prediction interval. I have predicted the next 24 values for my time series, but now I would also like to calculate the prediction interval for them (say 95% interval). How to do this? Can someone show me the steps? I found a pdf on the subject, but it only showed how to make the prediction interval for one step-forecast ... here is the pdf if you want to see ...

http://www.learningace.com/doc/2087382/d6c17c68ca3c0a03278d4a97276a0223/forecast-conf-int-11

**Update to question**:

When answering my question, could you please explain what to do and not redirect me to a R-package or something. I want to know what I'm doing.

Comment: What is your model (the model you have used for prediction)? I guess it is hourly data.

Comment: My model is ARIMA(5,0,8)(2,0,1) and yes, hourly data

Comment: Do you know how to generate prediction interval for AR(1) model? is AR(1) enough to generalize your model?

Comment: No I do not =) No I don't think that it is. Thank you for your reply!